# actionperformed on the main class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

So I'm creating a GUI that performs add,sub,multiply and divide but I need to have Components, Constructor, Process & Display should be in the Sub Class my problem is I can't get my answer button working.

sub class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class basic_arithmetic extends JFrame{

public JPanel panel1, panel2;
public JRadioButton sum, dif, pro, quo;
public JTextField n1, n2;
public JButton answer, clear;
public ButtonGroup button;
public comBHandler cbHandler;
public exBHandler ebHandler;
public static final int WID=400;
public static final int HGT=125;
public basic_arithmetic(){


    answer = new JButton("Answer");
    cbHandler = new comBHandler();
    answer.addActionListener(cbHandler);


    clear = new JButton("Clear");
    ebHandler = new exBHandler();
    clear.addActionListener(ebHandler);

    public class comBHandler implements ActionListener{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    }
}
public class exBHandler implements ActionListener{
    public exBHandler() {
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        n1.setText(null);
        n2.setText(null);
    }
    public void setButtonActionListener(ActionListener al) {
        answer.addActionListener(al);
    }
}
}
```

main class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class basic_arithmetic_caller{
public static void main(String[] args){
basic_arithmetic new = new basic_arithmetic();


    //if statement for answer button here
    }
}
```

Comment: *"..can't get my answer button working"*  Maybe it's on strike.  What exactly do you mean by 'working'?

Comment: Nothing is implemented in ActionListener for answer button. ``comBHandler` has empty `actionPerformed()` method.

Comment: I need my Answer button to show answer (see the main class)

Comment: I don't know how I can get my cbHandler to work with the main class

Comment: Why have you removed your code? This makes the questions and answers useless to other users

Comment: I returned it.. just need to delete something for personal purposes sorry instead I put "//if statements here"

Comment: Ok. Please be aware that anybody can see the complete revision history using the edit link below your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're completely missing the idea of event handling. All the code you have in the main method, is process right when you run the program. So none of your `isSelected()` will equate to true, as nothing has been selected yet.

In the context of event handling, when a user/or component does something, as event is fired/ For instance if you press a button, an ActionEvent is fired. A component needs a registered listener to listen for those events. When the even is fired, the interested listener catches the event and processes the callback.

For example, You have a button

```
JButton button = new JButton("Button");
```

Every time, the putton is pressed, it fires an `ActionEvent`. To be able to *"catch"* that event, you need a listener, that has an `actionPeformed` that is called when the event is fired.

```
public MyListener extends ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Button pressed");
    }
}
```

Now you just need to register the listener to the button. When the button is pressed, a series of calls will lead to the `actionPerformed` being called.

```
button.addActionListener(new MyListener());
```

Now all that being said, you need to do the exact same thing with with your radio buttons. You need to add a listener to it, so it will perform that code you have in your main method, when ever it it pressed.

Please see more at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html). Those three are in the `AbstractButton` family, so they have similar functionality.

You'll also note that different components have different listeners you can add, as they fire different events. You can see more about event handling/handlers at [Writing Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html)

Comment: thanks before I saw your answer I finally got it but thanks anyway :D